# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, system.io.file

I have the following method which resizes a given image and caches it

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 3600, VaryByParam = "id")]

    public ActionResult UserFace(int id)
    {
        var cacheKey = String.Format("userPhotoURICacheKey_{0}", id);
        var defaultFileCacheKey = String.Format("userPhotoDefaultCacheKey");

        HttpContext.Cache[cacheKey] = HttpContext.Cache[cacheKey] ?? UserService.GetPhotoURI(id) ?? string.Empty;
        var userPhoto = (String)HttpContext.Cache[cacheKey];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userPhoto))
        {
            var filename = id + ".jpg";


            //crop and resize
            var image = Image.FromFile(new Uri(userPhoto).LocalPath);

            const int resW = 200;
            const int resH = 200;

            var minEdge = Math.Min(image.Width, image.Height);
            var scaleFactor =(float) minEdge/Math.Min(resH, resW);

            var newImage = new Bitmap(resW, resH);
            var sufrace = Graphics.FromImage(newImage);
            sufrace.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

            sufrace.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, image.Width / scaleFactor, image.Height / scaleFactor);

            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            newImage.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            stream.Position = 0;
            var file = File(stream, "image/jpg", filename);

            return file;

        }
        HttpContext.Cache[defaultFileCacheKey] = HttpContext.Cache[defaultFileCacheKey] ?? File("~/Content/images/no_photo.jpg", "image/jpg", "nophoto.jpg");
        return (FileResult)HttpContext.Cache[defaultFileCacheKey];
    }
```

In another method I'm trying to update a cached image with a new one

```
public void UploadUserImage(byte[] arr, int userId)
    {
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
        stream.Write(arr, 0, arr.Length);
        using (var dataManager = factory.GetDataManager())
        {
            var userRepository = dataManager.GetRepository<IUserRepository>();
            var user = GetByID(userId);
            user.PhotoURI =
                        storageFactory.CreateFileStorageSender()
                            .Send(storageConfig.UsersPhotoPath, user.Id.ToString(), stream);
            user.PhotoSize = stream.Length;

            userRepository.Save(user);
            dataManager.Commit();
        }
    }
```

And I'm getting "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process" error.

Comment: Try searching. Dispose your image.

Comment: The `Image` in `UserFace`, and the `Stream` in `UploadUserImage`, both need to be in `using` blocks. The `MemoryStream` in `UserFace` should continue to _not_ be in a `using` block because it becomes part of the `FileStreamResult` which is created by the `File` call. ASP.NET MVC will call `Dispose` on the `FileStreamResult` when the result is executed..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dispose image after you're done with resize to use it again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to dispose the "file", "image" and "newImage" objects from your code. I think the handles to the file object is giving you this error.